# Access violation when using pointers/address as keys and values in CMap or std::map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, mfc

I'm trying to use the memory address or pointer type as a key and value, but for some reason I get access violations on insertion.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    std::map<MyClass*, MyClass*> stlMapPointer;
    std::map<size_t, size_t> stlMapAddress;
    CMap<MyClass*, MyClass*, MyClass*, MyClass*> mfcMapPointer;
    CMap<size_t, size_t, size_t, size_t> mfcMapAddress;
}

SomeOtherClass
{
public:
    SomeClass *m_someClassRef;
    void SomeOtherClass::some_method(MyClass* ptr, ...);
}

void SomeOtherClass::some_method(MyClass* ptr, ...)
{
    MyClass* test = ptr;
    size_t address = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(test); // I realize size_t is technically not portable

    // PROBLEM STARTS HERE:  Every single one of the following insertions will yield an access violation while calling various internal CMap/std::map calls.
    m_someClassRef->stlMapPointer.insert(std::pair<MyClass*, MyClass*>(test, test));
    m_someClassRef->stlMapPointer.insert(std::pair<size_t, size_t>(address, address));
    m_someClassRef->mfcMapPointer.SetAt(test, test);
    m_someClassRef->mfcMapAddress.SetAt(address, address);
}
```

MyClass does NOT have a copy constructor, but I thought this would be irrelevant.  I'm also stuck with Visual Studio 6, if that's at all relevant.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Where and how is `m_someClassRef` set? My guess is it's null.

Comment: Not quite so easy I'm afraid! In my real debugging code, I actually get the size of the maps before performing inserts (they're all zero, of course). One curious artifact is that CMap doesn't seem to be fully initialized, and so I have to deliberately call InitHashTable(<some size>, true).  If i don't do this, I get a divide by zero crash instead.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code posted (at least nothing that would cause a crash). Bug is somewhere else, post more code.

Comment: Thank you, your comments gave me the confidence to track down the problem.

Comment: `size_t address = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(test); // I realize size_t is technically not portable` Are you clear on what *exactly* this is supposed to do? You are reinterpreting a *pointer* (which may have a very large value) as a *size* which is a scalar.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  1.  I was storing the address location deliberately as a scalar as a sanity check and for debugging purposes only. 2.  size_t happens to be the same size as the heap address locations on the only platform I'm working on.  3.  uint_ptr is the type I should be using, but it's not something that ships with VS6 nor is it something I want to maintain when it's merely for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are curious:  The problem was that elsewhere within the application, a memset was being called on the SomeClass instance to initialize the memory.

What made this problem bedeviling (before noticing the memset):  The map members are regular instance members (and not pointers), leading to very odd-ball results where the Map member clearly exist but is left in a bad state.

Thanks to the comments, it occurred to me to try and change the SomeClass map members to pointers instead (e.g. CMap* mfcMapAddress).  Lo and behold, even after my constructor creates a CMap instance the pointer value gets wiped to zero.

Thank you!

Comment: The right fix is not to change everything to pointers, requiring careful manual memory management, it's to remove the `memset`, which is a terrible way to initialize a non-POD class. Write a constructor instead and fix it properly.

Comment: I agree. This completely breaks the RAII idiom and effectively made me waste many frustrating days. But that part isn't something I'm allowed to change, unfortunately.

Comment: Please take @JonathanWakely's advice about memset to heart: it's undefined behavior on anything but a POD.  You're certainly trashing CMap's vtable pointer by doing so with the declaration you originally had.

Comment: Good job on tracking it down. In addition to what @JonathanWakely said, I will add one thing: For future reference, a hint that the problem was `m_someClassRef` having an invalid value would be that all *four* insertions failed, and the only commonality between them was that they are all members of the same class.

Comment: _This completely breaks the RAII idiom_ it's not related to RAII, but it's still wrong. _But that part isn't something I'm allowed to change, unfortunately._ The kind of attitude that led to that restriction is why many people have bad things to say about  MFC apps. I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not fond of MFC, but for collection classes I only have a choice between (ancient) STL and MFC.  And I'm not thrilled about the work involved in upgrading this application, once (if?) we move to Visual Studio 201x!